# Javascript XmlHttpRequest bad connection

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

I keep running the following code but keep getting the "Bad connection" alert pop up, meaning I didn't get a successful response code.

Does anyone see anything wrong with the following script?

```
function process(){

URL = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }

else {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    alert("Successful connection!");
    }

 else {
    alert("Bad connection!");
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readyState passes through a number of other states (opened, sent, headers received, loading) before reaching state 4 (done). Each time the event fires, you'll get the Bad Connection alert until it is successful.

You probably want something more like:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert("Successful connection!");
    } else {
        alert("HTTP error: " + xmlhttp.status);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed this but now I keep getting HTTP error: 0. I tried for google.com , also, to make sure.

Comment: You [aren't allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) to access arbitrary 3rd party URLs. Use an HTTP URL on the same server as the page.

Comment: Is there any Javascript API to access/crawl 3rd party URLS? If not, how can accomplish this using a web language?

Comment: There is now way to directly access arbitrary 3rd party URLs using client side JavaScript. Any server side language will let you access whatever URLs you like (because you are running the code on your own computer and not on your visitor's computer with all your visitor's identifying features). (So pick any server side language (JavaScript is an option, e.g. via Node.js) and look for an HTTP client library for it)